# How to do a 1=1 left join with a HASH object

Tags: hash, sas

What I have and want to transform

```
proc sql;
create table indirect_costs as
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from dpd a
    left join efforts&costprod. b
on a.fnum = b.client_ref 
    left join (select * from costs where _name_= 'avg_effort_cost') c
on 1=1;
quit;
```

The first part is easy, it's the 1=1 that's bugging me because there is literally no key to work with, or at least a key I understand.

```
data indirect_costs;
    if 0 then set efforts&costprod. dpd costs(where _name_= 'avg_effort_cost');
    if _n_ eq 1 then do;
        dc="efforts&costprod.";
        declare hash h_cf(dataset:dc, hashexp:15, multidata:'Y');
        h_cf.defineKey('client_ref');
        h_cf.defineData(all:'Y');
        h_cf.defineDone(); 
        df="costs";
        declare hash h_df(dataset:df, hashexp:15, multidata:'Y');
        h_df.defineKey(all:'Y');
        h_df.defineData(all:'Y');
        h_df.defineDone(); 
        end;
    set dpd;
        rc_cf = h_cf.find(key:fnum);
        rc_df=h_df.find();
        do while (rc_cf=0 and rc_df=0);
        output;
        rc_cf =h_cf.find_next();
        rc_df=h_df.find_next();
        call missing(of _all_);
        end;
run;
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

What I want: To make this sql join a hash join.

What is stopping me: The statement 1=1.

What I need: A hash equivalent of the statement 1=1.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do given what? What does "transform" mean? What "parts"? What does "no key to work with" mean? And so what? Joins are not on keys, they are on conditions. (Inner join returns cross join rows meeting the condition. For 1=1 that's cross join rows. Left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. For 1=1 there are 2 cases: non-empty left table with empty right table returns left table rows extended by NULLs, otherwise the result is inner join rows, ie cross join rows.) PS For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Transform== recode the sql statement in to an equivalent HASH statement. The first part, is the first left join, the second part is the 1=1 join, which I would like to know how to formulate using a Hash approach.

I'm just not sure how the 1=1 logic can be translated to the Hash syntax.

Comment: @philipxy maybe this logic isn't good for HASH objects. As you said joins don't translate to keys.

Comment: Please just clearly say what you are trying to do & how you have tried to do it & give a [mre]. Clarify via edits, not comments. PS I have no idea what "joins don't translate to keys" could be trying to say things I said. (I know you are claiming that it means something I said but it's not clearly saying anything.) You continue to not write clearly. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Why are you loading all of the COSTS dataset into the HASH when in your SQL code you are only loading the observations that match the WHERE condition?  If you want to loop over a hash use the hash iterator.

Comment: What does the dataset `costs` have in it?  How many rows that match the `where` condition?  Can I guess... 1?

Comment: And... a rule of thumb on these questions, because if you don't improve them you won't be able to post at some point.  Include sample data.  Include details of the data.  In particular, you're changing working code to something else - why?  Say how big each dataset is, how many rows in the 'want' dataset, etc.  Otherwise you're not going to get good answers, and eventually StackOverflow will give you a question ban.

Comment: Can't test this right now, but I think it's just adding the average value to every row, so there is no key in this case. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Hash-join-with-multiple-tables/td-p/521069

Comment: Might be looking for CROSS JOIN.  If that is the case, you will need likely to nest iterate two hashes.

Comment: @Richard Can you help me out with that? If you type it in as an answer, then that's my question answered.

Comment: It certainly doesn't answer the question as posed - but as a bunch of us have said, you haven't put enough information in the question to answer it.  Please do so.  How many rows are in COSTS that have the value 'avg_effort_cost'?  How many rows are in the other datasets per ID?

Answer (score -1):

Consider these three sample tables.  YMMV

```
data vendors(label='vetted vendors');
  do vendorid = 1 to 12;
    output;
  end;
run;

data projects(label='may reference unvetted vendors');
  call streaminit(2021);
  do projectid = 11 to 13;
    do vendorseq = 1 to rand('integer', 1, 6);
      /* mock up, no project has vendor 3, 5, or 7 */
      do until (vendorid not in (3 5 7));
        vendorid = rand('integer', 1, 12);
      end;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data costs_across;
  call streaminit (2021);
  do method = 1 to 5;
    array c cost1-cost7;
    do over c;
      c = rand('integer', 10,50);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc transpose data=costs_across out=costs;
  by method;
  var cost:;
run;
```

INNER and 1:1

```
data threeway;

  if 0 then set vendors projects costs;
 
  declare hash vendors (dataset:'vendors', ordered:'a');
  vendors.defineKey('vendorid');
  vendors.defineData(all:'yes');
  vendors.defineDone();

  declare hash projects (dataset:'projects', ordered:'a');
  projects.defineKey('projectid', 'vendorseq');
  projects.defineData(all:'yes');
  projects.defineDone();

  declare hash costs (dataset: 'costs(where=(_name_="cost3"))');
  costs.defineKey('method','_name_');
  costs.defineData(all:'yes');
  costs.defineDone();

  declare hiter p_iter('projects');
  declare hiter c_iter('costs');

  do while(p_iter.next() = 0);
    if vendors.check() = 0 then do;  /* same as criteria projects.vendorid=vendors.vendorid */
      matchcount+1;
      put 'INFO: ' matchcount= projectid= vendorseq= vendorid=;
      do while(c_iter.next() = 0);  /* same as criteria 1=1 */
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

LEFT JOIN mimicry requires more iterations

```
data threeway_left;
  if 0 then set vendors projects costs;
 
  declare hash vendors (dataset:'vendors', ordered:'a');
  vendors.defineKey('vendorid');
  vendors.defineData(all:'yes');
  vendors.defineDone();

  declare hash projects (dataset:'projects', ordered:'a', multidata:'y');
  projects.defineKey('vendorid');
  projects.defineData(all:'yes');
  projects.defineDone();

  declare hash costs (dataset: 'costs(where=(_name_="cost3"))', ordered:'a');
  costs.defineKey('method','_name_');
  costs.defineData(all:'yes');
  costs.defineDone();

  declare hiter v_iter('vendors');
  declare hiter c_iter('costs');

  call missing(of _all_);
  do while (v_iter.next() = 0);  /* full iteration mimics left of join */

    rcp = projects.find();

    if rcp ne 0 then do;
      /* no match in right, all missing */
      do while(c_iter.next() = 0);  /* same as criteria 1=1 */
        output;
      end;
    end;
    else do;
      /* iterate over the right matches */
      do until (rcv = 0);
        /* iterate over the costs */
        do while(c_iter.next() = 0);  /* same as criteria 1=1 */
          output;
        end;

        projects.has_next(result:rcv);
        if rcv then projects.find_next();
      end;
    end;

    call missing(of _all_);
  end;

  stop;
  drop rcv rcp;
run;
```